# itext failing to attach files when adding more than 60 attachments

Tags: java, itext

Using iText 5.  One of the last point releases but not the last one.  Didn't observer anything in release notes that would hint at this being a bug that was resolved.

Using the standard code block like this:

```
for (.... 73 File objects) {
   PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer, ... );
   fs.AddDescription("specificname", false);
   writer.AddFileAttachment(fs);
}
```

We basically add files from disk in a loop.  I verified that it's not the files.  We are adding 73 files total (xlsx mostly) and the output PDF has no attachments.  If we add 59 or 60 it works.  Any more than that and it fails.

The xlsx files are small.  I researched itext and PDF spec information.  There are no limits other than available memory.

So has anyone else encountered this?  Can someone run a test if possible to see what happens?

I tried using the existing set of files.  Add the first half and the output PDF is fine.  Add the second half of the file set and I get a correct output PDF.  So it's not hte files I am attching that is the issue.

I've also inspected the itext source code and do not see any sort of hard coded limitation on attachment count.

Comment: I checked the itext 5 source code (You can Google it it's available on GitHub) and I couldn't find any limitation on the attachment number. DId you try to debug and "enter" inside the classes of itext to see what's going on?

Comment: As you don't share enough code to reproduce the issue, please share your test output PDFs, both with all 73 attached at once (where you see none) and with them attached in 2 batches (where you see them all).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue.

I tried the following:

```c#
using (Document document = new Document())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, File.Create(resultFile));
    document.Open();

    document.Add(new Paragraph("Test file with 73 attachments"));

    for (int i = 0; i < 73; i++)
    {
        PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer,
                String.Format("folder/file_{0}.txt", i),
                String.Format("File {0}.txt", i),
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("Contents of file {0}", i)));
        fs.AddDescription("specificname", false);
        writer.AddFileAttachment(fs);
    }

    document.Close();
}
```

*([AddMultipleFileAttachments](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/csharp/annotate/AddMultipleFileAttachments.cs) test `Add73Files`)*

The result is a file with 73 attachments, and Adobe Acrobat does display them.

Thus, there appears to be an aspect to your code or use case that you don't mention but that is causing the issue.

---

*Tested using iText 5.5.13.3*